# Issues with SonarQube Integration with VSTS with multiple MSbuild projects

Tags: build, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

**In my build definition I have couple of Java & multiple MS build projects**. Java projects are built using Ant. There are multiple ANT & MSbuild steps in build defination

I want to integrate my build with SonarQube. I referred to this link https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS to add one begin analysis and one end analysis tasks,these tasks are added almost in the beginning & end of the build defination. Hence there are only 2 Sonar task & in between there are number of ms build and Ant tasks. When I run my build then I get some weird results on SonarQube. it seems like it scanned only part of codebase not the entire codebase.

I have following questions

1. Does SonarQube VSTS integration supports multiple MSbuild projects inside a same build definition. If Yes, can anyone please give pointers how to do that.
2. I have couple of Ant tasks as well. Is it supported by Sonar task? (its name says MSBuild task, is it applicable for Ant as well)?

Atul Sureka

Comment: Why do you want to analyze everything in one step? Why not use multiple dedicated builds?

Comment: I have gated check-in policy, I want to do sonar analysis with every build which happens with every check-in - Atul